# What is the simplest way to create plain JSF2.2 application in Maven?

Tags: maven, jsf-2.2

I need to create plain JSF 2.2 web application for Tomcat 8 with minimal libraries set. What maven command should I use?

Yet is simplest for me is use

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=http://myfaces.apache.org
```

and select item 7. But this way makes pom.xml with both myfaces and mojarra libraries. WHere can I found example of command or full source of pom.xml? Is there something like [wicket quickstart](http://wicket.apache.org/start/quickstart.html)?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Is the answer working out for you?

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar Yes! I've created new Maven project in Eclipse and tested this, but my web.xml is more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't really need a "command" to start your project, it's as simple as ..

**1) A simple pom.xml with the JSF API and its implemention**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6</version>
</dependency>
```

**2) a simple web.xml with the `FacesServlet` declaration and mapping to the pages**

```
<!-- JSF mapping -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- Map these files with JSF -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**3) You're good to go ..**